# quotient of complex numbers?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

so I was wondering if you have two different equations having denominators $2+i$ and $2-i$ respectively how came the denominator of the quotient in standard form is $5$ for both equations? I tought the denominator was given by $a^2 + b^2$ for $z/w$? ? I mean looking at the first "denominator" wouldnt that be $3$? since $4 + i^2$ and $i^2 =-1$?

$$\begin{align}
\ z &= x+yi \\
\ w &= a + bi \\
\end{align}
$$

I was also wondering about something else and thats how to simplify $(2+i)^3$ ? I got something like $\sqrt{5} (\cos(3 \tan^{-1} (1/2) + i \sin(3 \tan^{-1} (1/2))$ which gave me $2/5 + (11/5)i$, but in the solution is says only $2 + 11i$??

Comment: $(2+i)^3 = (2+i)(2+i)(2+i)$, and just FOIL.

Comment: You should be thinking of "$a+b\mathrm{i}$".  $2 + \mathrm{i}$:  $2^2+1^2 = 5$.  $2 - \mathrm{i}$:  $2^2+(-1)^2 = 5$.

Comment: ahh ok thanks, no wonder I was confused then :O, and also @user7530 how would you simplify (2+i)^100 then? cuz im pretty sure there is an easier way using the angle and modulus or whatever :P?

Comment: Sure, but it's only "easier" when the exponent is large.

Comment: Also notice that $\sqrt{5}\cos\left(3 \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{5}$ so it's possible you already have the right answer.

Comment: FK! I figured it out, it was just one simple mistake and thats cuz I forgot to raise root 5^3 :(((

Comment: This is called **rationalizing the denominator**. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/120716/242) for a general viewpoint and some interesting exmaples.

Comment: "Equation" is the wrong word here.  "Expressions" is correct, but in this case I would have been more specific and said "fractions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard trick for simplifying quotients of complex number is to multiply both the numerator and the denominator by the conjugate of the denominator.

Let $w \neq 2+\mathrm{i}$ and $z\neq 2-\mathrm{i}$ be two complex numbers. Notice that $2+\mathrm{i}$ is the conjugate of $2-\mathrm{i}$ and vice-versa. Consider the following:

$$\frac{w}{2+\mathrm{i}} = \frac{w(2-\mathrm{i})}{(2+\mathrm{i})(2-\mathrm{i})}=\frac{w(2-\mathrm{i})}{4-2\mathrm{i}+2\mathrm{i}+1}=\frac{w(2-\mathrm{i})}{5}$$

$$\frac{z}{2-\mathrm{i}} = \frac{z(2+\mathrm{i})}{(2-\mathrm{i})(2+\mathrm{i})}=\frac{z(2+\mathrm{i})}{4+2\mathrm{i}-2\mathrm{i}+1}=\frac{z(2+\mathrm{i})}{5}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general trick to evaluate $\frac{a+bi}{c+di}$ in the form $x+yi$ (i.e. how to divide one complex number by another).

We use the fact that $(c+di)(c-di)\equiv c^2+d^2 $ (prove it yourself!)

$\color{green}{\frac{a+bi}{c+di}}=\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\cdot \underbrace{\left(\frac{c-di}{c-di}\right)}_{1}=\frac{(a+bi)(c-di)}{(c+di)(c-di)}=\frac{ac-adi+bci+bd}{c^2+d^2}=\frac{(ac+bd)+(bc-ad)i}{c^2+d^2}=\color{green}{\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}+\left(\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}\right)i}$